# Create CMake target that copies files/dirs but excludes some items

Tags: c++, cmake, copy, target

I am trying to generate a CMake target for a C++ project using `add_custom_target` that copies the contents of the directory in which the `CMakeLists.txt` resides into `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, *but excludes a given list of files*.

While it looks like a quite easy task, I'm facing problems here. My attempts so far:

**1) Generate a list of all files/dirs, remove the items to be excluded and use the CMake copy command:**

```
file(GLOB files_to_copy LIST_DIRECTORIES TRUE *)
list(REMOVE_ITEM files_to_copy
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file_to_exclude.txt
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir_to_exclude
  # ...
)
add_custom_target(my-target
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${files_to_copy} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Problems:

- Removing items this way works on a string comparison level, which could lead to problems when using symbolic links, for example
- The [`copy` command line tool](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) apparently supports copying directories, however it doesn't seem to work on my machine, therefore directories *do not* get copied.

**2) Use the file command to copy the files, excluding some files**

```
file(COPY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  PATTERN "file_to_exclude.txt" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN "dir_to_exclude" EXCLUDE
)
```

Problems:

- This does exactly what I want, except that the command is not bound to a target and therefore is always executed. But I only need the copy operation to be a target.

Is there any possibility to bind the `file(COPY ...)` command to a target? Or any other straightforward solution to achieve what I want?

Please note that I only want to use CMake built-in tools and not execute any OS-specific shell commands (working on a cross-platform project).

Answer (score 2):

CMake [scripting commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-commands.7.html#scripting-commands) work only in **CMake context** and are executed *immediately*.

But a `COMMAND` in `add_custom_command` (or `add_custom_target`) is executed in the context of a **build tool** (e.g. Makefile), not in CMake context.

However, you may put CMake scripting commands into **separate CMake script**, and call this script from the `COMMAND`. This solution has the same platform-independent properties as `CMakeLists.txt` itself.

You may parameterize separate script either:

1. With `configure_file` CMake command.
2. By passing `-D` parameters to CMake when call the script.

The first approach is quite simple: you write the script as would you write `CMakeLists.txt` itself. But it generates additional files for every parametrization set.

The second approach is useful for multi-purpose (or multi-usable) scripts, as it doesn't create additional copy of the script for every usage. But it requires some design of the parameters.

### Using 'configure_file'

**copy_sources.cmake.in** (as if commands are written in `CMakeLists.txt`):

```
file(COPY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  PATTERN "file_to_exclude.txt" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN "dir_to_exclude" EXCLUDE
```

)

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Instantiate the parameterized script in the binary directory.
configure_file(copy_sources.cmake.in copy_sources.cmake)

add_custom_target(my-target
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/copy_sources.cmake
```

)

### Using '-D' parameters

**copy_sources.cmake**:

```
# Expect the script to be called from the source directory.
# This saves one parameter.
# 
# DEST_DIR denotes the directory for copy to.
file(COPY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/" DESTINATION ${DEST_DIR}
  PATTERN "file_to_exclude.txt" EXCLUDE
  PATTERN "dir_to_exclude" EXCLUDE
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_target(my-target
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -DDEST_DIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} # all '-D' options should preceed '-P' one
    -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_sources.cmake
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} # The script assumes proper current directory
```

)